# How do I install Visual Studio CTP updates?

Tags: installation, troubleshooting, updates, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to install the "Visual Studio Tools for Git" extension in VS2012 Ultimate, but it says I need an update. It takes me to a "VS2012 Update 2 CTP 3" page, with 10 separate files (some big).

Which/How do I install? The "...Agents/TFS/Express/Full" options are throwing me off, and I can't find better instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick the one that says "vsupdate_KB2707250.exe". It will launch an installer and download everything you need.

Be sure that you have previously installed Update 1

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was confused because that update is so small in size -- I thought that it was just some kind of patch or security fix. So are the other files listed just extraneous?

Comment: The other ones are the individual upgrades for tooling if you want to install just a segment of the whole update

Comment: BTW, the final version of Update 2 is already out. Scott Hanselmann and Scott Gu blogged about it a couple of days ago: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReleasedASPNETAndWebTools20122InContext.aspx